# Watching route in VueJS3 leads to an error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this piece of code in my VueJS3 component:

```
watch(route, () => {
  loadData();
  findFilter();
});
```

`loadData` calls an API loading data, it works fine.
I put this watcher so that when a user calls the same component with another route, the data reloads. Indeed: I have filters, and my URLS are like this: `example.com/thepage/optionalFilter`.
`optionalFilter` is optional, I can even have no filter. If I don't use this watcher, the component doesn't reload the data corresponding to the new filter.
But when I use this watcher, I have a warning in the console in development mode:

`Avoid app logic that relies on enumerating keys on a component instance. The keys will be empty in production mode to avoid performance overhead`

And in production mode, the first time I have an error in the console, then if I refresh everything goes fine:

`exception { name: "NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED"...`

I think my problem comes from the fact I badly watch the route. Am I?

By the way, I tried to use `key` in my `router-view`, but it calls every function inside the `onMounted` block.

Comment: This [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2027) would be help.

Comment: Thanks, I already read it but I really don't see how it can help me. I have the impression it concerns a cyclic reference to an ID.

Comment: Have you tried `watch(route.params.xxx, ...)`?